# How to check if a function is in a vector in R?

Tags: r, list, vector

I want to do do something like `pnorm %in% c(pnorm, pt, pchisq)`, but this doesn't work.

What could I do instead?

Comment: `sapply(fun_list, identical, x)` ?

Comment: R doesn't like the comparison `pnorm == pnorm` either.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Came here to offer the same suggestion. You should write up in an answer I think.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thank you. Could you explain what the arguments `identical` and `x` represent?

Comment: I second @duckmayr 's suggestion that Moody should write it up as an answer, perhaps wrapping it in an `any()`

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Is possible there is a better way to do you actual goal.

Comment: I pass a cumulative distribution function into a function, and want to make sure it is  either `pnorm`, `pt`, `pchisq`.

Comment: I made my comment into an answer, with an additional way using `%in%`

Comment: @John Coleman `==` only works for atomic and list types as error says. So one should use `identical(pnorm, pnorm)` or not to check environments `isTRUE(all.equal(pnorm, pnorm))`, or `list(pnorm) %in% list(pnorm)` which would be a special case of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
pnorm %in% c(pnorm, pt, pchisq)
```

results in error :

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :  'match' requires vector
>   arguments

Indeed `%in%` calls `match` and `?match` tells us (slightly reformatted):

> *x* : vector or NULL: the values to be matched.

We can make it work by making your function a 1 element list :

```
list(pnorm) %in% c(pnorm, pt, pchisq)
# [1] TRUE
```

However, a more idiomatic way of doing what you want is to apply the function identical on your list of functions, it will loop on your function elements and check for each one if it's identical to `pnorm` :

```
sapply(c(pnorm, pt, pchisq), identical, pnorm)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

To get a your desired output, wrap inside any :

```
any(sapply(c(pnorm, pt, pchisq), identical, pnorm))
# [1] TRUE
```

These 2 methods are **not** strictly equivalent however because identical is more strict and will check the environment while the first solution will only check the arguments and body (i.e. the output of `as.list(fun)),` see :

```
pnorm2 <- function (q, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) 
  .Call(C_pnorm, q, mean, sd, lower.tail, log.p)

environment(pnorm2)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
environment(pnorm)
# <environment: namespace:stats>

any(sapply(c(pnorm, pt, pchisq), identical, pnorm2))
# [1] FALSE
list(pnorm2) %in% c(pnorm, pt, pchisq)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with purrr:

```
has_element(c(pt,pnorm,pchisq),pnorm)
#[1] TRUE
has_element(c(pt,pchisq),pnorm)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`%inl%` <- function(z,l) !is.null(Find(function(x) identical(x,z),l))
pnorm %inl% c(pt,pchisq)
#[1] FALSE
pnorm %inl% c(pt,pnorm,pchisq)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Some explanation about your answer would be very handy!